# creating a table with DECIMAL(11,2) as variable keep getting 0.00

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am new to PHY MySQL and PHPmyadmin.  Creating a table with and inserting decimals as the variable .  The table is created but shows 0.00 as my number.  my columns is configured as
`amount` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL,

I insert into the table:

```
INSERT INTO  
`amount`(`amt_id`,`amount`)
VALUES
('1', '$625545.00'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `$` sign in the value:

```
INSERT INTO amount(amt_id,amount) VALUES ('1', '625545.00');
```

**Note:** MS SQL has a `money` field that can allow such values, but not MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you're entering string value (by using "$") in the field with data type DECIMAL (which is one type of numeric field). First you need to remove "$" from the value. And since you've set DECIMAL of 11,2 then it would be any value with **".00"** even after saving only **625545**. So, any of below will work for you:

```
INSERT INTO amount(amt_id,amount) VALUES ('1', '625545.00');
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO amount(amt_id,amount) VALUES ('1', '625545');
```

Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering a string:

This:

```
INSERT INTO amount(amt_id,amount) VALUES ('1', '$625545.00'),
```

is Equivalent to

```
 INSERT INTO amount(amt_id,amount) VALUES ('1', 'helloworld'),
```

If you want to enter data in a DECIMAL(11,2) field, be sure to enter something like `12345.22`